# How to use RKValueTransformers.h along with RestKit

Tags: restkit-0.20

The RKValueTransformers's version is 1.1.0 and RestKit's is 0.20.3, both installed by cocoapods. After installation, I find in project there is 2 RKValueTransformers.h file, one is  standalong RKValueTransformers, and the other is in RestKit. They cause conflict in building phase, does anyone know how to resolve this problem?
The compile error is:
/Code/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:85:5: Unknown type name 'RKDateToStringValueTransformer'; did you mean 'RKCompoundValueTransformer'?

Comment: You added both projects in pods yourself, or you just added RestKit?

Comment: @Wain, both projects were added, actually they were managed by cocoapods, so there were 2 targets in Pods project: RKValueTransformers and RestKit.

Comment: So you tried removing value transformers and just using the one that is included with RestKit?

Comment: No, I didn't tried, cause I want to use the standalone one (in https://github.com/RestKit/RKValueTransformers), not the one inside RestKit. But I couldn't easily remove value transformers inside RestKit since there was logics using the transformers.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I'm not sure you will be able to (without copying locally and renaming files)

Comment: @Wain, I followed the example project in RestKit source code pulled from Github. In that example ('RKTwitterCoreData' project), it uses RKValueTransformer which is defined in standalone RKValueTransformers file. After that I wanted to build my own project, I installed RestKit and RKValueTransformer by cocoapods, then I encountered this problem.

Comment: @Chengjiong were you able to solve this problem? I also encountered the same issue while adding both RestKit and RKValueTransformers.

Comment: @RahulJiresal, no solution yet, after several failed try, I changed my plan to not use RKValueTransformers:(

Comment: I got it to compile. Writing down the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the RestKit version to the latest one (0.23.3). Or the first one which has `RKValueTransformers` as a dependency (0.21.0). Then remove `RKValueTransformers` from the podfile. RestKit will add it automatically as a dependency.

Reasoning --

This is what was happening -- RestKit versions 0.20.3 (and earlier) have its own version of `RKValueTransformers` (.h and .m). So when you have RestKit 0.20.3 and also add RKValueTransformers, RestKit still refers to its own version, and not the pod you added. When you upgrade your version of RestKit, it starts referring to the pod dependency.